# Spark word count example : why error: value split is not a member of Char at the REPL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

From the Spark example (https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) , the code looks like:

```
    val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
     val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

And works when compiled.
However, if i try this exact code at the Spark REPL:

```
scala> val lines = "abc def"
lines: String = abc def

scala> val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
<console>:12: error: **value split is not a member of Char**
       val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
                                   ^
```

What gives??

thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines` is just a string. So `flatmap` is being run against a sequence of characters. You need to use an RDD

```
val rddYouCanUse = sc.parallelize(List("abc def"))
```

Comment: Great. And, side question: when doing that, rddYouCanUse becomes an RDD[String]. how does rddYouCanUse.flatMap(_.split(" "))  get evaluated - what does '_' refer to ? an 'instance' of RDD within the list ?

Answer (score 2):

`file` is probably an `Iterator[String]` or something like that. In your code, `lines` is just a `String`. No iterator. That means when you flatMap the `String`, you're treating the `String` as the collection, so each element is a `Char`. And `Char` doesn't have `split` as a method (doesn't make sense).

If you break it out a little..

```
val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
                          ^ this is a Char
```

You can just split on the string itself.

```
val words = lines.split(" ")
```